# Repeating loop conditions in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have a form filling application. I am taking inputs from the user and then proceeding ahead as required. I am trying to repeat a condition. My reprex-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(reshape2)
library(pool)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

df <- structure(list(Category = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C","D", "D"), 
                     Subcategory = c("A_1", "A_2", "A_3", "B_1", "B_2", "C_1", "C_2", "D_3", "D_4"), 
                     Option = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))

ui<- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
               titlePanel("Form"),
               fluidRow(column( width = 8,
                                div(id='outDiv',
                                    
                                    panel(style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px; position:relative; align: centre",
                                          textInput("message", label = "",placeholder = "Type your message here."),
                                          actionButton("send", "Send"), heading = "Student Services", status = "primary")
                                )
               )))

server<- function(input,output, session)

{
  ############Clear Function##############
  clearInput<- function()
  {
    updateTextInput(session,"message", value = "")
  }
  
  unique_Categories1<- df%>% distinct(Category)
  
  emojis<- matrix(c("Happy", "Confused", "Worried"), byrow =F, nrow = 1)
  emj <- reactiveValues(em = 1 )
  
  types<- matrix(c("Pre Acceptance Queries", "Post Arrival Challenges"), byrow =F, nrow = 1)
  type_tp <- reactiveValues(tp = 1 ) 

  
  pre_cat<- matrix(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), byrow =F, nrow = 1)
  pre_1 <- reactiveValues(pt = 1 )    
  
  
  #Function to call
  call_function<- function(a, lvl)
  {
    lvl<-1
    a<-  insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                  ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                          div(class="bubble admin",
                             
                              wellPanel(
                                p(paste("No worries!", emoji("smiley") , "I can help you in-")))), tags$br(),
                          wellPanel(
                              actionBttn("TP1","Pre Acceptance Queries",   style = "pill", size = "xs"),
                              actionBttn("TP2","Post Arrival Challenges", style = "pill",size = "xs")
                          )), immediate = TRUE)
    
    
    runjs(' document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView(); ')
    shinyjs::disable("message")
    shinyjs::hide("send")
    shinyjs::disable("mood1")
    shinyjs::disable("mood2")
    shinyjs::disable("mood3")
  }
  
  ############################################ Pre Landing questions ####################################################
  
  admission_cat_quest<- reactive({
    df%>%filter(Category=="A")%>% group_by(Category)%>% distinct( Subcategory, Option)
  })
  
  ################################################### Main function######################################################
  replyMessage<- function(lvl,msg)
  {
    
    switch(lvl,
           
           # Check for Level 1
           if(grepl("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$",msg, perl=T))
           {
             
             insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                      ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                              div(class="bubble admin",
                                  
                                  wellPanel(
                                    p("Hi",tags$b(msg),".",tags$br(), "My name is Zeta!","How are you feeling today?")), tags$br()),
                              wellPanel(
                                  actionBttn("mood1","Happy", style = "pill", size = "xs"),
                                  actionBttn("mood2","Confused", style = "pill",size = "xs"),
                                  actionBttn("mood3","Worried",  style = "pill",size = "xs")
                              )), immediate = TRUE)
             clearInput()
             shinyjs::disable("message")
             shinyjs::hide("send")
             lvl(lvl + 1)
             runjs('
                    document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView();
                 ')
             
           },
           
           # Check for Level 2
           
           if(msg=="Happy" | msg=="Confused" | msg=="Worried")
           {
             if(msg=="Happy")
             {
               
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                                div(class="bubble admin",
                                   
                                    wellPanel(
                                      p(paste("It sounds great!", emoji("smiley") , "How can I help you now?")))), tags$br(),
                                wellPanel(
                                    actionBttn("TP1","Pre Acceptance Queries",  style = "pill", size = "xs"),
                                    actionBttn("TP2","Post Arrival Challenges",style = "pill",size = "xs")
                                )), immediate = TRUE)
               
               lvl(lvl + 1)  
               runjs(' document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView();')
               shinyjs::disable("message")
               shinyjs::hide("send")
               shinyjs::disable("mood1")
               shinyjs::disable("mood2")
               shinyjs::disable("mood3")
               
             }
             else if(msg=="Confused"| msg=="Worried")
             {
               message(lvl)
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                                div(class="bubble admin",
                                    
                                    wellPanel(
                                      p(paste("No worries!", emoji("smiley") , "I can help you in-")))), tags$br(),
                                wellPanel(
                                    actionBttn("TP1","Pre Acceptance Queries",   style = "pill", size = "xs"),
                                    actionBttn("TP2","Post Arrival Challenges", style = "pill",size = "xs")
                                )), immediate = TRUE)
               lvl(lvl+1)
               runjs(' document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView(); ')
               shinyjs::disable("message")
               shinyjs::hide("send")
               shinyjs::disable("mood1")
               shinyjs::disable("mood2")
               shinyjs::disable("mood3")
               
             }
           },
           
           
           if(msg=="Pre Acceptance Queries" | msg=="Post Arrival Challenges")
           {
            
             if(msg=="Pre Acceptance Queries")
             {
               message(lvl)
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                                div(class="bubble admin",
                                    
                                    wellPanel(
                                      p(paste("It sounds great!", emoji("smiley") , "How can I help you now?")))),
                                wellPanel(
                                    actionBttn("PRE1",unique_Categories1[1,1],  style = "pill", size = "xs"),
                                    actionBttn("PRE2",unique_Categories1[2,1], style = "pill",size = "xs"),
                                    actionBttn("PRE3",unique_Categories1[3,1],  style = "pill",size = "xs"),
                                    actionBttn("PRE4",unique_Categories1[4,1],  style = "pill",size = "xs")
                                )), immediate = TRUE)
               
               lvl(lvl + 1) 
               runjs(' document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView(); ')
               shinyjs::disable("message")
               shinyjs::hide("send")
               shinyjs::disable("mood1")
               shinyjs::disable("mood2")
               shinyjs::disable("mood3")
             }
             
           },
           
           if(msg=="A")
           {
              
             call_function(a)
             
             
             
           }
           
           
           
           
           
    )
  }
  
  # Function to check blank in Message box
  getMessage<- function(lvl)
  {
    # Observer Event for Message Box
    observeEvent(input$send,{
      if(input$message == '')
      {
        insertUI(
          selector = "#message",
          where = "beforeBegin",
          ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
                 div(class="bubble admin",
                     img(),
                     p("Kindly provide a valid input."))
          )
        )
        clearInput()
      }
      else
      {
        replyMessage(lvl(),input$message)
      }
      
    })
    
    lapply(sprintf("mood%s", 1:3),
           function(x)
           {
             observeEvent(input[[x]],{
               emj$em<- as.numeric(sub("mood", "", x))
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        p(paste(
                          replyMessage(lvl(),emojis[, emj$em])))
               )
             })
             shinyjs::disable("mood1")
             shinyjs::disable("mood2")
             shinyjs::disable("mood3")
             
           })
    
    lapply(sprintf("TP%s", 1:2),
           function(x)
           {
             observeEvent(input[[x]],{
               type_tp$tp<- as.numeric(sub("TP", "", x))
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        p(paste(
                          replyMessage(lvl(),types[, type_tp$tp])))
               )
             })
             shinyjs::disable("mood1")
             shinyjs::disable("mood2")
             shinyjs::disable("mood3")
             
           })
    
    lapply(sprintf("PRE%s", 1:4),
           function(x)
           {
             observeEvent(input[[x]],{
               pre_1$pt<- as.numeric(sub("PRE", "", x))
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        p(paste(
                          replyMessage(lvl(),pre_cat[, pre_1$pt])))
               )
             })
             shinyjs::disable("mood1")
             shinyjs::disable("mood2")
             shinyjs::disable("mood3")
             
           })
    
  }
  
  
  # Main Function
  startConversation<- function()
  {
    
    clearInput()
    insertUI(
      selector = "#message",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
             div(class="bubble admin",
                 wellPanel(
                   p("Hey! Could I get your name?")
                 ))))
    getMessage(lvl)
    
  }
  
  # Declaring and Initializing Global Variables
  i <<- 1
  lvl <<- reactiveVal()
  lvl(i)
  
  startConversation()
  
  
  #Invalid Function
  invalidInput<- function()
  {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#message",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
             div(class="bubble admin",
                 wellPanel(
                   p("Kindly provide a valid input")))
      ), immediate = TRUE
    )
    clearInput()      
  }
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I have created lvl function(like counter) which increases when the condition proceeds ahead. I am trying to repeat the condition of **Pre Acceptance Queries** (in reprex) when condition (if=='A'). I have created a UI in create_function in server part and calling it. But it's showing the UI part only(of if=='A'), it's not proceeding after that.
For usage of the application- Kindly **enter a text**, then select and **Mood**(Happy, Confused and Worried) then go to **Pre Acceptance queries** then select **A**.

Comment: Please comment out all the libraries you are not using in this code.  Are you sure this is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  You have posted almost 350 lines of code.  It does require some time to even review it.

Comment: Hi YBS, I have updated the code. Removed the unwanted libraries. It's actually the part of the code.

Comment: What should it do after selecting A in Pre Acceptance queries?  It displays the same previous choice for me.  Please note that I am not able to install pool package, so I have commented out that one library.

Comment: Hi YBS, when I select A, pre acceptance queries should open again and it should proceed as usual. Like- From Pre acceptance->something->A->Pre acceptance>something->A...... so on.. As long as keep selecting the 'A', it should repeat...