# adding dynamic ui in data table output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data table with 3 Columns (Name, Number and Status). **Name** column has all values, **Number** column has some missing values and **Status** column have all rows as blanks.
I am trying to add dynamically generated ui,(selectInput), in the blank rows of Status column and show it as a datatable output.

My reprex-

```
library(reshape2)
library(reshape)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(magrittr)
library(devtools)
library(devtools)

ui<- fluidPage({
  fluidRow(4,
           DTOutput("dt"))
})


server<- function(input, session, output)
{
#Creating reactive data table(as my datatable is also dynamically generated in real project)
  dt<- reactive({
    dt<- data.table("Name"=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), "Number"=c(1,2,3,4,"",6, ""),"status"=c(rep(NA, 7)),stringsAsFactors = F)
 return(dt)
     })

# Creating dynamic selectInput
  slct<- reactive({
    lapply(1:nrow(dt()), function(i)
    {
     selectInput(paste("a",i), "Status", c("Open", "Close")) 
    })
  })
  
#Check for blank condition of Status column and adding dynamic selectInput in blanks
  opt<- reactive({
    ifelse(dt()$status=="NA", slct(), dt()$status)
  })
  
# Data table output
  observe({
    output$dt<- renderDataTable({
     opt()
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question!

Comment: No problem. Can you help me in - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704069/repeating-loop-conditions-in-r

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in **Rcommunity**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    title = 'Slider Inputsa table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    m <- matrix(
      1:12, nrow = 12, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, "initial_slider_values")
    )
    m2 <- m
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {

      m2[i, ] <-selectInput(inputId = month.abb[i],
                          label = month.abb[i],
                          choices = c(m[i, ],m[i, ]-1),
                          selected = m[i,]) %>% as.character
      }
    m2
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m2, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-slider-input');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel <- renderPrint({
      str(sapply(month.abb, function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
)
```